Can I compare intercepts between GLMs and GLMMs to estimate the effect of a random effect?
I’m working on a statistical analysis where I’ve run both generalized linear models (GLMs) and generalized linear mixed-effects models (GLMMs) on the same dataset. Can I interpret the difference between the intercepts of the GLM and the GLMM? Is it valid to say that the difference between these two intercepts represents the effect size of the random effect? If not, is there a standard approach or formula to adjust the GLMM intercept to estimate what it would be if there were no random effects (effectively making it comparable to the GLM intercept)?


Is there a reason you used both a GLM and a GLMM? I would think you would only need one depending on your assumptions about random effect variance or non-independence in the data. If the residuals are non-independent in the GLM, then any inference based off them is not as trustworthy.

Thank you! I use both a GLM and a GLMM to address two aspects:
Overall variation: The GLM shows me the overall variation in a binary outcome without accounting for individual-level variability. This gives an understanding of the trend across the entire sample and a baseline of how the population as a whole behaves.
Impact of random effects: By adding a random effect in a GLMM, this allows me to see how much of the variation is due to differences between individuals. The GLMM also let's me identify specific respondents who contribute most to the variation, which is not possible with the GLM.

Then you should look at the estimated random effect, see how large its variance is, instead of comparing fixed effect intercepts.

Thank you. In the GLMM, the variance for the random effect is 26.5, which is quite large, and the fixed intercept is 7.5052. When I run the GLM version, the fixed intercept is 2.85607. I initially thought that subtracting the random effect variance from the GLMM intercept might bring it closer to the GLM intercept, but this is clearly not the case. I want to capture the overall variation as if the random effect were not present. I'm trying to understand how to get the overall variation from the GLM and the individual-level variability from the GLMM. Could I calculate the ICC from the GLMM?

The random effect is centered around zero, so subtracting the random effect from the fixed effect intercept, you would end up with the same intercept. Subtracting the variance does not result in anything meaningful. As for ICC, I'm not sure what you mean, because a generalized linear mixed model does not have an error variance (only a random effects variance), unless you are using a Gaussian error structure, in which case you should use an ordinary linear mixed model instead.
